# Algorithm confusion in codewars

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, numbers

So here is the problem:

The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollars bill. A "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.

Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.

Can Vasya sell a ticket to each person and give the change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people follow in the line?

Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to each person and give the change. Otherwise return NO.

My code:

```
function tickets(peopleInLine) {
  var speakVasya = "";
  var vasyaValue = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++) {
    if (peopleInLine[i] - 25 > vasyaValue) {
      speakVasya = "NO";
      break;
    } else {
      vasyaValue += 25;
      speakVasya = "YES";
    }
  }
  document.write(speakVasya);
}


tickets([25, 25, 50]);
```

Live demo here 
https://jsfiddle.net/py234z11/1/

My problem is, according to codewars,my solution passes 7 tests but fails at 2, but i can't understand which ones as it doesn't give the arguements which puts in tickets function.

Comment: I feel like there is a lot of required information missing. If everyone has a 25 dollar bill and a ticket is 25 then he won't need any change and can just sell each person in line one ticket.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan yes sorry english is not my first language and trying my best to explain it. So if everyone had 25 dollars in a lets say line of 30 people ie tickets([25,25,25,25....]) the programm will print YES as it should because she would never run out of money. But if the first guy had 25 and second guy had 100 dollar bill waiting for 75 change, poor Vasya would not have any spare change so it would print NO

Comment: Without seeing your input lines how can we tell.

Comment: I worked as a cashier in a cinema in Europe and we used to refuse entrance to people who only had 25-euro banknotes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting the amount of money he holds is not enough - you need to keep track of the count of the bills.

For example, if you have one $100 bill, you cannot make change for someone with a $50 or $100 bill, you need the specific bill (the $25 bill to make change for $50, and $25 and $50 OR three $25 bills to make change for the $100 bill).

So rather than keep a total money collected, keep track of the number of bills collected.

Comment: Also, if somebody has a $100 you need to give them the $50 + $25 if you have it, and not 3 x $25.

Answer (score 0):

My C# solution for this problem, edited

```
public static string CanSellTickets(int[] peopleInLine) {

        int count25 = 0;
        int count50 = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < peopleInLine.Length; i++) {
            if (peopleInLine[i] == 25) {
                count25++;
            }
            else if (peopleInLine[i] == 50) {
                if (count25 == 0) {
                    return "NO";
                }
                else {
                    count25--;
                    count50++;
                }
            }
            else if (peopleInLine[i] == 100) {
                if (count50 >= 1 && count25 >= 1) {
                    count25--;
                    count50--;
                }
                else if (count50 == 0 && count25 >= 3) {
                    count25 = count25 - 3;
                }
                else {
                    return "NO";
                }
            }
        }

        return "YES";
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to switch the order of the first two $100 cases.  If we pass back three $25 bills when we could pass back one $50 and one $25, we may run out of $25 bills, when we otherwise we'd have enough.  For example, `[25, 25, 50, 50, 25, 25, 25, 100, 100]`  In your technique when we hit that last customer, the till contains two $50 bills and one $100, and we can't make change.  If we switched those two case, then it would contain two $25 bills, one $50, and one $100, so we can make change for this last customer.